# sticky positioning in email for IOS 7

Tags: webkit, html-email, ios7, sticky

For iOS email I'd like to have a fixed position banner.

I am using:
{ position: -webkit-sticky !important; top: 10px !important; }

But in the iOS 7 email app the fixed position function & Sticky function are not working.

Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

this is Ros from Campaign Monitor - we've been testing position: -webkit-sticky; position: sticky; with no luck so far. Overall, position: fixed remains the answer in email clients other than Apple iOS & Mail, however we hope this will change to extend to iOS 7 Mail in time.

Answer (score 0):

Try using position fixed and declare the top/left/right etc:

```
 position: fixed; top:0; left: 0; right: 0;
```